# Use countif to determine boolean in a class module

Tags: class, excel, boolean, vba

I'm trying to use a Boolean within a class module however the code fails at “MsgBox LOADPROPS.DUPLICATES”  with “Public Property Get DUPLICATES() As Range” Please can someone assist?

```
 Sub INITIALIZE_CLASS()
    Dim LOADPROPS As cLoadData
    Set LOADPROPS = New cLoadData
    LOADPROPS.DUPLICATES = PasteLoadingForm.Columns("K")
    MsgBox LOADPROPS.DUPLICATES
End Sub
```

and in the class module

```
Public Property Get DUPLICATES() As Range
    DUPLICATES = pDUPLICATES
End Property

Public Property Let DUPLICATES(Value As Range)
    Dim lcount As Long
    lcount = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Value, "DUPLICATE")
    '
    pDUPLICATES = lcount
        Select Case pDUPLICATES
            Case Is = 0
                pDUPLICATES = False
            Case Is >= 0
                pDUPLICATES = True
            Case Else
                MsgBox "Error"
        End Select
End Property
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I can tell, you're mixing up the data type of DUPLICATES. You are declaring it as a range in the get function, yet pDUPLICATES can take on the value of a boolean and long (initially is the count then converted to true or false in the select statement).

The quick fix would be to change them to variants, so your class module becomes:

```
Private pDUPLICATES As Variant

Public Property Get DUPLICATES() As Variant
    DUPLICATES = pDUPLICATES
End Property

Public Property Let DUPLICATES(Value As Variant)
    Dim lcount As Long
    lcount = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Value, "DUPLICATE")
    '
    pDUPLICATES = lcount
        Select Case pDUPLICATES
            Case Is = 0
                pDUPLICATES = False
            Case Is >= 0
                pDUPLICATES = True
            Case Else
                MsgBox "Error"
        End Select
End Property
```

**EDIT**

To avoid variants, a better approach might be to restructure your class module so you're not actually using get/set properties (which you're not really doing here). You could do it with a function as follows:

*Class cLoadDataV2*

```
Option Explicit

Public pDUPLICATES As Boolean

Public Function fDuplicates(rngInputRange As Range)

    Dim lcount As Long

    lcount = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(rngInputRange, "DUPLICATE")

    Select Case lcount
        Case Is = 0
            pDUPLICATES = False
        Case Is >= 0
            pDUPLICATES = True
        Case Else
            MsgBox "Error"
    End Select

End Function
```

*Regular module*

```
Sub Initialise_v2()

    Dim LOADPROPS As cLoadDataV2
    Set LOADPROPS = New cLoadDataV2

    LOADPROPS.fDuplicates (Sheet1.Columns("K"))
    MsgBox LOADPROPS.pDUPLICATES

End Sub
```